# Prove that if $a \mid b$ and $b \mid c$, then $a \mid c$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help with proving this:

> Prove that if $a \mid b$ and $b \mid c$, then $a \mid c$.

My initial start was as the following:
\begin{align*}
a \mid b = a*b\\
c \mid b = a*c
\end{align*}
so combining $a+c=[a*b]+[c*b]$, then I am lost.

Comment: Try writing $a|b$ as $b = ak$, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a|b \to b=an$ for some $n \in \Bbb N $

If $c=bm $ for some $m \in \Bbb N $, then by substitution $c=anm $.

By closure of $\Bbb N $ under multiplication, $mn \in \Bbb N $.

Thus $a|c$

Answer (score 3):

If $a|b$, then $b = m \times a$ for some $m$. Similarly, $b|c$ implies $c=n\times b$ for some n. Then note that
$$
c = n\times b = n\times (m\times a) = (n\times m) \times a.
$$
Hence, $c$ is a multiple of $a$ for $n\times m$, thus $a|c$.

Comment: You should state that $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then explain why $nm \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of $|$: $a \ | \ b$ is the same as saying there is some $t_1 \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that
$$a=t_1b$$

Also, $b \ | \ c$, so:
$$b=t_2c$$

Now, try substituting the second equation into the first equation to get:
$$a=t_1(t_2c)=(t_1t_2)c$$

How does the above equation show that $a \ | \ c$ using the definition of $|$? Figuring that out is your part. Good luck!